# How to download code from gitlab to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I´m trying to download code from gitlab to kubernetes. I have created an ubuntu docker image.

Here is the yaml file. I have created a token from gitlab to download the rep. The problem is that i don´t know where to copy the gitlab token to allow kubernetes to download the code ??

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: syncrepo-gitlab
spec:
  containers:
  - image: fake.eu.io/testseq-362663/ubuntu:latest
    name: gitlab
    volumeMounts:
    - name: git-source
      mountPath: /tmp/git
    env:
    - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
      value: https://myrep/scripts.git
    - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
      value: git-sync
    - name: GIT_SYNC_SSH
      value: "true"
  volumes:
  - name: git-source
    emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Pass it directly as an environment variable:

```
env:
    - name: GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME
      value: <deploy_token_username>
    - name: GIT_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD
      value: <deploy_token_password>
```

This is not recommended, because anyone that can see your Pod manifest will see your Gitlab token.

**Option 2** Create a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for the token and mount it to the pod.

```
kubectl create secret generic gitlab-deploy-token -–from-literal=username=<deploy_token_username> -–from-literal=password=<deploy_token_password>
```

This will create an encoded secret in your k8s namespace.

To mount the secret:

```
  - name: GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: gitlab-deploy-token
        key: username
  - name: GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: gitlab-deploy-token
        key: password
```

Now, in your pod, you can:

```
git clone http://$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME:$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

> Note: Special characters such as $, *, and ! require escaping. If the
>   password you are using has special characters, you need to escape them
>   using the \ character. For example, if your actual password is
>   S!B*d$zDsb, you should execute the command this way: kubectl create
>   secret generic dev-db-secret --from-literal=username=devuser
>   --from-literal=password=S!B\*d\$zDsb You do not need to escape
>   special characters in passwords from files (--from-file).

Comment: Thanks so much but not sure i got it.
gitlab gives you a name to the deploy token (e.g  gitlab+deploy-token-395111) and a password (e.g: 63xksj29450_)

What is `<your token>` in the kubeclt secret statement ?
I have tried to add the password but i get an error.

Comment: More over should i the given name for the token, in the exemple `gitlab+deploy-token-395111`

I have tried but get an error:

`kubectl create secret generic gitlab+deploy-token-395111 --from-literal=token=63xksj29450_`

I get an error
`Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'â' in -–from-literal=token=63xksj29450_`

Comment: Since this is a deploy token you should pass both the username and the password.
You get this error because you should escape special characters of the password.
I edited the answer with more info.

Comment: I still get the same error. I do not have specias $,*, !
`>kubectl create secret generic gitlab-token  -–from-literal=username=gitlab+deploy-token-395111  -–from-literal=password=63xksj29450_`
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'â' in -–from-literal=username=gitlab+deploy-token-395111

Don´t know what is wrong since there is no  â in my username or password ???

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the dashes in "-–from-literal"
Replace "-–" with "--" and it will work.